# How to get USPS shipping rate in asp.net mvc

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, web-services, razor, xsd

In my shopping cart,i just want to shipping rate of UPSP.

I have `USPS Userid and Password`.

When I apply above property to upsp xml(testing api.dll --- RateV2) they throw me error like as below :

```
Invalid XML Element content is invalid according to the DTD/Schema.
Expecting: Machinable.
```

I have checked usps xml format from https://www.usps.com/webtools/htm/Rate-Calculators-v1-3.htm

but stll i got error.

Can any one help me.
how to solve this error..

Answer (score 1):

pass the value for the machinable as true which is the default value.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a version problem.  The URL you refer to above appears to point to RateV4, but you say your testing dll is for RateV2.

Comment: I just replace V4 to v2 because they not providing xml format for testing api(V2).